# Java when to catch general Exceptions and specific Exceptions

Tags: java, performance, exception, try-catch

I am always using catch (Exception e) {//whatever} but is that actually correct ? Why should I use specific exceptions if general Exception works for everything ? Does it somehow affect the performance ?

Comment: There's no performance difference, but in the case of specific exceptions, you can handle them specifically to recover from the error. If you're just catching `Exception`, then the best you can do is print its stack trace. But if, for example, you're building an ATM/Banking app, you could catch an `InsufficientFundsException` and treat it differently than say, `InvalidPinException`.

Answer (score 4):

> I am always using catch (Exception e) {//whatever} but is that actually correct ?

No. That goes against good recommendation to catch the most appropriate specific exception.

> Why should I use specific exceptions if general Exception works for everything ?

Because exceptions you don't really expect can be masked.
For example, when performing some database operations,
a `SQLException` might happen, which is expected,
and you can implement handling it gracefully.
And if a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` gets thrown,
that would be unexpected, and most probably indicate a programming error.
But if instead `SQLException` you catch `Exception`,
then you might never know that the unexpected `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` was thrown.
And the graceful cleanup might also not apply for this kind of exception.

Using specific exceptions also makes the code more readable:
the reader can understand what kind of things can go wrong in the code guarded by the `try-catch`.

Related to this is that when you declare a method to throw an exception,
the declaration should use the exception that's most appropriate to the abstraction.

> Does it somehow affect the performance ?

Not at all.